# Quotation marks too close with textqq

Tags: quotation

I noticed that with font type `garamondx` the distance of the quotation mark and the neighboring character is different when using `,,''` and `\textqq`. What can be the reason? How to adjust this distance?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textqq{quote}
    
,,quote''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what causes it, but my first try to at least make it look good when compiled would be to stick a \hspace{1pt} between the quotation mark and the quote.

Comment: well the reason is that the definition of \textqq changes the distances. You could change \textqq, but I would load `\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}` and use \enquote{quote}, that works with other languages too.